# How do you load test a wing rib?

Tags: wing, aircraft-structures

When builders say they load tested a wing, most of the time what they are saying is that they load tested the wing spar(s) by turning the plane upside down and putting weights on the wing. This procedure doesn't load test the ribs, so how do you load test a single rib?

Comment: It seems like loading the wing would load up the whole wing, not just the spars.

Comment: What country are you asking about? As far as I know, there is no requirement to test single ribs, just the assembly as a whole. Testing a single rib may be meaningless anyway since it obtains (and contributes) strength in regards to the entire structure, not just the single structural member.

Comment: @RonBeyer based on OP's track record, they are asking for the purposes of a homebuilt ultralight, and their country is Nigeria.

Comment: Testing a rib by itself may not give proper results. If the rib is kept straight as by a metal skin when assembled into a wing, testing without the skin will cause a failure at much lower load.

Comment: @DavidTeahay I'd say proctoring it the SAT or GED would give it considerable amounts of stress, so if you do that you'll have to be careful it doesn't crack. If it does well, then good luck to your new wing going off to a wonderful university! :P

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Rib is load tested upside down with weights on its flat bottom side to simulate air deflection during flight,and two ropes holding the rib up at positions where the spars will sit.